# Can I set a default address in the "To:" header for outgoing mails in the EMail app?

Tags: email

On my phone I mostly send emails to myself and I'd like to save the few clicks from selecting a recipient.

Is there a way to prepopulate the "To:" field with my address?
Or any other email client which supports this? It has to support Hotmail.

Comment: If you ever tear yourself away from Hotmail and start using Gmail, the "note to self" voice command does this.

Answer (score 6):

You could create a shortcut on your home screen to your Contact info.

First make sure you've got an entry for yourself in your Contacts with your email address (not the "Me" Contact, but an extra one).

Then go into your Applications screen, tap the Widgets tab at the top, find either the 4x1 or 1x1 "Contact" widget and add that to an empty spot on your Home screen, when prompted find your Contact in the list.

Now when you want to create a new email just tap your Contact icon on the Home screen, tap the EMail icon and it should open up a new email, with your email pre-populated in the To box.

Answer (score 5):

I know it's a workaround, but I frequently use [SelfMail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.javatomic.drupal&hl=en), which adds itself to the pretty-much-universal "Share" action. As an example, open a picture, select Share, and pick it from the list.

Answer (score 5):

- You could just save drafts (with GMail), no need to send the massage at all.

or

- You do not need to use the "To:" header to send yourself mail at all but instead can send email to a `default-BCC field and leave the "To:" empty.

[K9](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fsck.k9) allows this:

[image]

Comment: +1 for saving as drafts.  As soon as the message is saved, it immediately becomes available on all GMail clients (web, Android, etc.)  Works great with attachments as well.